# How to sub-license a modified MIT licensed project as a copyright?

Tags: mit, copyright, license

I searched for this question over the internet but with no success.

I got a MIT licensed python library and did my modifications to fit my necessities. I want this new version to be a copyright with all rights reserved. I know that even if I don't say anything, this new project is automatically under all rights reserved to me. Even so, I want to add some note that indicates the copyright, as the same way the MIT License note previously added in the original project.

The most common practice for licencing is adding a `LICENSE` file to the root dir with the license text. For sub-license as a "all rights reserved", what is the main procedure or the common procedure? How, in practice, can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The MIT license requires you to preserve the original copyright & license notice as a kind of attribution, but you can make it clear that it's no longer in effect. For example, you might write a license notice like this:

> Copyright 2020 Your Name
>
> All rights reserved.
>
> This software is based on libfoobar:
>
> > Copyright 2017 Original Author
> >
> > (Full text of MIT License here.)

You could put such notices into a LICENSE file, but would probably also want to update any license headers in files that you modified.

Comment: This answer could help. There is no formal way to do this like a documented template right? As long as it's clear in some part of the software, right?

Comment: @WoolfDall There's no template or something, but some prior art. E.g. Python went through a few different licenses, with the old licenses still being preserved due to similar requirements to keep the license intact. [Here is their license and history document](https://docs.python.org/3/license.html), which also includes attribution for bundled third party libraries. For the old license, it explicitly states which Python versions were covered by it.

Comment: ok. Thank you!!